# How do i preserve "\" on a insert statement?

Tags: python, mysql

i created asimple code in order to seek for all files on a drive and insert the results into a table. But, when it tries to insert, instead inserting into the table the value y:\somedir\file.txt, the code inserts y:somedirfile.txt.

How can i do to insert and preserve the backslashes from directories?

Bellow, the code im using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import datetime
import re
import MySQLdb
import sys
import fnmatch
import os


def insert_db(sql):

    conn = None
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='somehost', db='somedb',
                          user='someuser', passwd='somepass',
                          )
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
    except MySQLdb.Error, e:
        conn.rollback()
        print "Error "
        print e.args
        sys.exit(1)


def read_file():
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('y:\\'):
        for loop in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.*'):
            Values = dict()
            filename =  os.path.join(root, loop)
            (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(filename)
            modtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(time.ctime(mtime), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
            fsize = os.stat(filename).st_size
            sql ="""insert into pvcs (date,name,size) values ('%(DATE)s',"%(FILE)s",'%(SIZE)s');
            """ % {'DATE':modtime,'FILE':filename,'SIZE':fsize}
            insert_db(sql)
            #print sql
            #time.sleep(5)
```

example output:

```
insert into pvcs (date,name,size) values ('2013-05-30 17:08:12',"y:\somedir\change.log",'2196815');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not use `%` string formatting with SQL queries! As you can see it works bad, and it's also terrible insecure.

Comment: i know, but its just for a one time work. For this task i will use executemany, but since i want do debug how to make this work i changed for this way. but thanks for remind it for the readers =)

Comment: Seems you didn't realise that that's _the actual_ issue with your code. Your query is literally executed as if you typed it into `mysql` prompt, so `\s` is getting interpreted as an escape sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `insert_db()`:

```
def insert_db(sql, data):
    ...
    cursor.execute(sql, data)
```

below:

```
sql = "insert into pvcs (date,name,size) values (%s,%s,%s)"
data = (modtime, filename, fsize)
insert_db(sql, data)
```